# How to pick a vector graphics element quickly in lots of elements

Tags: graphics, vector

How to quickly "pick" a 2d element in large number of vector graphics elements, such as polylines, polygons, curves etc.
In Qt, QGraphics can do this easily, but In my program, I don't need this class, I just need QPaint and QWidget.I want to manage and render these elements data myself.
So..
Which related graphics knowledge I need to search in google?, BSP-tree?R-tree?

Give me some advice, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is more designed for picking than a BSP-tree. According to the wikipedia article on [Spatial Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index), R-tree is

> Typically the preferred method for
>   indexing spatial data. Objects
>   (shapes, lines and points) are grouped
>   using the minimum bounding rectangle
>   (MBR). Objects are added to an MBR
>   within the index that will lead to the
>   smallest increase in its size.

But are you sure it's worth your while to implement the creation, maintenance, and use of the R-tree rather than using QGraphics?

Comment: Thanks very much! For some applications such as wellLog visualization, contour plot etc, several views maybe composited into a window. So I think QWidget is more light-weight than QGraphicsView. I ..don't know is this right..:)